# Экранирование в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, экранирование

Вот пока не сэкранировал таким образом `currency:"+'"RUB"'+"`, скрипт не передавал в обработку другому скрипту реализацию от тега `<a>`.
В документации к скрипту прописано просто `currency:'RUB'`.
Перепробовал кучу экранирований. И так `'"`, и так `""`, и эдак`''`, и пришёл к своему варианту через конкатенацию, лишь она сработала. Неужели более оптимального экранирования для данной ситуации нет?
*(Как-то, на мой взгляд громоздко всё это выглядит)*
**Error - при нажатии "Оплатить", это уже результат правильной сработки скрипта, не берите его в оборот.**

```js
function Change_value() {

  var x = document.getElementById("item_select");
    
      if (x.value == 'first_price') {
   document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input name='sum' required='required' size='64' type='text' value='11000' class='input_field' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#666666;'><br><br><a class='btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary' onclick='ipayCheckout({    amount:11000,    currency:"+'"RUB"'+",    order_number:0,    description:0 },    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })'>Оплатить</a>";
   //alert("x= "+x.value);
  }
    
if (x.value == 'second_price') {
   document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input name='sum' required='required' size='64' type='text' value='20200' class='input_field' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#666666;'><br><br><a class='btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary' onclick='ipayCheckout({    amount:20200,    currency:"+'"RUB"'+",    order_number:0,    description:0 },    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })'>Оплатить</a>";
   //alert("x= "+x.value);
  }    

if (x.value == 'third_price') {
   document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input name='sum' required='required' size='64' type='text' value='50400' class='input_field' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#666666;'><br><br><a class='btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary' onclick='ipayCheckout({    amount:50400,    currency:"+'"RUB"'+",    order_number:0,    description:0 },    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })'>Оплатить</a>";
   //alert("x= "+x.value);
  }   


 }
```

```html
  <form>Выберите услугу для оплаты<span style="color: red;">*</span><br />
<select required id="item_select" class="input_field" style="width: 308px;" onchange="Change_value()">
<option value="null" style="color: #000000;">выберите услугу для оплаты</option>
<option value="first_price" style="color: #000000;">первый ценник</option>
<option value="second_price" style="color: #000000;">второй ценник</option>
<option value="third_price" style="color: #000000;">третий ценник</option>
</select>
<br><br>

  
  <div id="Output" style="display: inline;">
<input name="sum" readonly required="required" size="64" value="0" class="input_field" style="background-color: #e0e0e0; color: #666666;" type="text" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Я почти ничего не понял, все зависит от дальнейшей обработки этого текста, однако в вопросе ничего про это нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной ситуации, можно написать `\"RUB\"` вместо `"+'"RUB"'+"`

```js
function Change_value() {

  var x = document.getElementById("item_select");
    
      if (x.value == 'first_price') {
   document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input name='sum' required='required' size='64' type='text' value='11000' class='input_field' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#666666;'><br><br><a class='btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary' onclick='ipayCheckout({    amount:11000,    currency:\"RUB\",    order_number:0,    description:0 },    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })'>Оплатить</a>";
   //alert("x= "+x.value);
  }
    
if (x.value == 'second_price') {
   document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input name='sum' required='required' size='64' type='text' value='20200' class='input_field' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#666666;'><br><br><a class='btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary' onclick='ipayCheckout({    amount:20200,    currency:\"RUB\",    order_number:0,    description:0 },    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })'>Оплатить</a>";
   //alert("x= "+x.value);
  }    

if (x.value == 'third_price') {
   document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input name='sum' required='required' size='64' type='text' value='50400' class='input_field' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#666666;'><br><br><a class='btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary' onclick='ipayCheckout({    amount:50400,    currency:\"RUB\",    order_number:0,    description:0 },    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })'>Оплатить</a>";
   //alert("x= "+x.value);
  }   


 }
```

```html
  <form>Выберите услугу для оплаты<span style="color: red;">*</span><br />
<select required id="item_select" class="input_field" style="width: 308px;" onchange="Change_value()">
<option value="null" style="color: #000000;">выберите услугу для оплаты</option>
<option value="first_price" style="color: #000000;">первый ценник</option>
<option value="second_price" style="color: #000000;">второй ценник</option>
<option value="third_price" style="color: #000000;">третий ценник</option>
</select>
<br><br>

  
  <div id="Output" style="display: inline;">
<input name="sum" readonly required="required" size="64" value="0" class="input_field" style="background-color: #e0e0e0; color: #666666;" type="text" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: т.е. аналогично, как в PHP? Никогда бы не подумал! Ведь знал и думал - ведь это их другого ЯП.

Comment: @I_CaR экранировать кавычки в JS'е так же как и в PHP, но, необходимо учесть, что различие в кавычках между языками есть, например, в JS между одинарной кавычкой и двойной нет отличий по функционалу, а в PHP есть. Так же в JS'е есть обратная кавычка со своим функционалом..